# Get values from a deeper nested multi dimension array

Tags: php, json, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have the following json_decode($array, true); datas of multiple hotels.

```js
array: 10[▼
    "HotelName" => "AL MANZIL DOWNTOWN DUBAI"
    "PreferredStatus" => "A"
    "PropertyType" => "City Hotel"
    "StarRating" => "4"
    "GeoLocation" => array: 2[▶]
    "Chain" => "ADDRESS HOTELS"
    "HotelCode" => "32-4560"
    "HotelDescr" => []
    "Zone" => "Downtown"
    "RoomTypeDetails" => array: 1[▼
      "Rooms" => array: 1[▼
        "Room" => array: 18[▼
          0 => array: 23[▼
            "RoomNo" => "1"
            "RoomType" => "DELUXE ROOM"
            "RoomTypeCode" => "14264"
            "RoomStatus" => "OK"
            "BlackOut" => array: 2[▶]
            "CurrCode" => "AED"
            "ContractTokenId" => "191032"
            "RoomConfigurationId" => "1"
            "DynamicInventory" => "N"
            "ContractLabel" => []
            "Refundable" => "Y"
            "PackageYN" => "N"
            "MealPlan" => "ROOM ONLY"
            "MealPlanCode" => "1380"
            "RoomNumber" => "1"
            "BuyRate" => []
            "CommissionSellCharges" => []
            "TaxSellCharges" => []
            "Rate" => "3430.4"
            "RoomStatusDetails" => array: 1[▶]
            "SupplementDetails" => array:1 [▼
              "Supplement" => array:12 [▼
                 "Id" => "403880"
                 "FromDate" => "20191015"
                 "ToDate" => "20191018"
                 "Qty" => "1"
                 "Rate" => "127"
                 "CommissionSellCharges" => []
                 "TaxSellCharges" => []
                 "BuyRate" => []
                 "Name" => "CHILD SUPPLEMENT"
                 "OptionalYN" => "N"
                 "ValidOn" => "YYYYYYY"
                 "Nights" => "4"
               ]
             ]
            "DiscountDetails" => array: 1[▼
              "Discount" => array: 8[▼
                "DiscountName" => "EARLY BIRD OFFER 2019-2020  20 % DISCOUNT"
                "DiscountType" => "Price Reduction Discount"
                "DiscountNotes" => "<html><body><p><strong>EARLY BIRD OFFER 2019 - 2020 | 20% DISCOUNT <br /><br />Terms and Conditions:</strong> <br />- Applicable for all booking received&nbsp;6 ▶"
                "DiscountTypeCode" => "0"
                "TotalDiscountRate" => "857.6"
                "CommissionSellCharges" => []
                "TaxSellCharges" => []
                "TotalDiscountBuyRate" => []
              ]
            ]
            "PromotionalContract" => "N"
          ] 1 => array: 23[▼
            "RoomNo" => "1"
            "RoomType" => "DELUXE ROOM"
            "RoomTypeCode" => "14264"
            "RoomStatus" => "OK"
            "BlackOut" => array: 2[▶]
            "CurrCode" => "AED"
            "ContractTokenId" => "191032"
            "RoomConfigurationId" => "1"
            "DynamicInventory" => "N"
            "ContractLabel" => []
            "Refundable" => "Y"
            "PackageYN" => "N"
            "MealPlan" => "BED AND BREAKFAST"
            "MealPlanCode" => "1376"
            "RoomNumber" => "1"
            "BuyRate" => []
            "CommissionSellCharges" => []
            "TaxSellCharges" => []
            "Rate" => "4019.2"
            "RoomStatusDetails" => array: 1[▶]
            "SupplementDetails" => array: 1[▶]
            "DiscountDetails" => array: 1[▶]
            "PromotionalContract" => "N"
          ]
```

I can use a foreach loop to get values of a specific hotel as such below code,

```
//All the hotel names
@foreach ($array['Hotels']['Hotel'] as $key => $hotel){

echo $hotel['HotelName']; //Displays all the hotel names
}

// All the RoomTypes of a single hotel array
@foreach ($hotel['RoomTypeDetails']['Rooms']['Room'] as $k => $rt {

  echo $rt['RoomType'];  //Displays all the RoomTypes of a hotel
}

//I would like to get the discounts of a single room type of a hotel
@foreach ($rt['DiscountDetails'] as $d { 

  echo $d['DiscountName'] // NOT WORKING - Throws error, Undefined index - 
  NEED HELP HERE
}

//I would like to get the supplements of a single room type of a hotel
@foreach ($rt['SupplementDetails']['Supplement'] as $s { 

  echo $s['Name'] // NOT WORKING - Throws error, Undefined Index - NEED HELP  
  HERE
}
```

I'm developing using laravel framework, v5.7, these datas are XML Responses via an Remote API, json decoded to use it in my app. I have been trying to figure out how to echo deeper nested elements of arrays inside of an multi dimension array.

I would like to get the following hierarchy of values from the above json output datas.

1. Hotel > Room > Rates(discounts)
2. Hotel > Room > Supplements

I have searched stack overflow and other forums and i have found some scenarios and possible solutions too, have applied some too, yet it doesn't seem to display the values i need.

Tried nested for each functions still i couldn't get it work. If you guys have any experience with these kinda data, Please lend me a help or direct me for the best practices to work with deeper nested multi dimension array.

If wondering here is the dump for the variable $rt [ its already inside a single hotel element ]

```js
array: 23[▼
  "RoomNo" => "1"
  "RoomType" => "DELUXE ROOM"
  "RoomTypeCode" => "14264"
  "RoomStatus" => "OK"
  "BlackOut" => array: 2[▶]
  "CurrCode" => "AED"
  "ContractTokenId" => "191032"
  "RoomConfigurationId" => "1"
  "DynamicInventory" => "N"
  "ContractLabel" => []
  "Refundable" => "Y"
  "PackageYN" => "N"
  "MealPlan" => "ROOM ONLY"
  "MealPlanCode" => "1380"
  "RoomNumber" => "1"
  "BuyRate" => []
  "CommissionSellCharges" => []
  "TaxSellCharges" => []
  "Rate" => "3430.4"
  "RoomStatusDetails" => array: 1[▶]
  "SupplementDetails" => array: 1[▼
    "Supplement" => array: 12[▼
      "Id" => "403880"
      "FromDate" => "20191015"
      "ToDate" => "20191018"
      "Qty" => "1"
      "Rate" => "127"
      "CommissionSellCharges" => []
      "TaxSellCharges" => []
      "BuyRate" => []
      "Name" => "CHILD SUPPLEMENT"
      "OptionalYN" => "N"
      "ValidOn" => "YYYYYYY"
      "Nights" => "4"
    ]
  ]
  "DiscountDetails" => array: 1[▼
    "Discount" => array: 8[▼
      "DiscountName" => "EARLY BIRD OFFER 2019-2020  20 % DISCOUNT"
      "DiscountType" => "Price Reduction Discount"
      "DiscountNotes" => "<html><body><p><strong>EARLY BIRD OFFER 2019 - 2020 | 20% DISCOUNT <br /><br />Terms and Conditions:</strong> <br />- Applicable for all booking received&nbsp;6 ▶"
      "DiscountTypeCode" => "0"
      "TotalDiscountRate" => "857.6"
      "CommissionSellCharges" => []
      "TaxSellCharges" => []
      "TotalDiscountBuyRate" => []
    ]
  ]
  "PromotionalContract" => "N"
]
```

Thanks so much!
Aisar

Comment: Why do you use `@foreach` all the time, `@` should only be used when really necessary and this isn't.

Comment: As you say you get the data in XML, it would be easier if you tried to process that using something like SimpleXML rather than the route your taking.  Whatever you do, it is worth adding the original data rather than displaying the resultant array, it helps others test code before answering.

Comment: I have use 
  $xml= new \SimpleXMLElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

  $json = json_encode($xml);
  $dump = json_decode($json,TRUE);

Comment: I have used the foreach in the necessary view files of a single hotel to display room details and supplements. Foreach is necessary. or  what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Getting some value doesn't need loop.

```
//All the hotel names
@foreach ($array['Hotels']['Hotel'] as $key => $hotel){

    echo $hotel['HotelName']; //Displays all the hotel names

    // All the RoomTypes of a single hotel array
    @foreach ($hotel['RoomTypeDetails']['Rooms']['Room'] as $k => $rt {

      echo $rt['RoomType'];  //Displays all the RoomTypes of a hotel


      //I would like to get the discounts of a single room type of a hotel
      if(isset($rt['DiscountDetails']['Discount']['DiscountName']))
          echo $rt['DiscountDetails']['Discount']['DiscountName'];
      else
          echo 'No discount';

      //I would like to get the supplements of a single room type of a hotel
      if(isset($rt['SupplementDetails']['Supplement']['Name']))
          echo $rt['SupplementDetails']['Supplement']['Name'];
      else
          echo 'No Supplement';

    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me same error, Undefined index: DiscountName - any other suggestions

Comment: Refere to my edit. It's possible that some Hotel doesn't have Discount Details. So you must check before echo the value

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see you forget some parts of your code, indexs

```
@foreach ($rt['RoomTypeDetails']['Rooms']['Room']['DiscountDetails'] as $d { 

  echo $d['DiscountName'];
}


@foreach ($rt['RoomTypeDetails']['Rooms']['Room']['SupplementDetails']['Supplement'] as $s { 

  echo $s['Name'];
}
```

Comment: Please refer my edits for the question, i have included the dump for the variable $rt . indexes looks fine. But don't think your foreach loop would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Helper Function e.g data_get(), even collections functions such as `get()`, `pluck()`, etc to work on *Arrayable* Items.

Lets use `data_get()` as example to get all the `MealPlan` using this path `RoomTypeDetails->Rooms->Room->*-> MealPlan`:

```
$data = [
            "HotelName" => "AL MANZIL DOWNTOWN DUBAI",
            "PreferredStatus" => "A",
            "PropertyType" => "City Hotel",
            "StarRating" => "4",
            "GeoLocation" => [],
            "Chain" => "ADDRESS HOTELS",
            "HotelCode" => "32-4560",
            "HotelDescr" => [],
            "Zone" => "Downtown",
            "RoomTypeDetails" => [
                "Rooms" => [
                    "Room" => [
                        0 => [
                            "RoomNo" => "1",
                            "RoomType" => "DELUXE ROOM",
                            "RoomTypeCode" => "14264",
                            "RoomStatus" => "OK",
                            "BlackOut" => [],
                            "CurrCode" => "AED",
                            "ContractTokenId" => "191032",
                            "RoomConfigurationId" => "1",
                            "DynamicInventory" => "N",
                            "ContractLabel" => [],
                            "Refundable" => "Y",
                            "PackageYN" => "N",
                            "MealPlan" => "ROOM ONLY",
                            "MealPlanCode" => "1380",
                            "RoomNumber" => "1",
                            "BuyRate" => [],
                            "CommissionSellCharges" => [],
                            "TaxSellCharges" => [],
                            "Rate" => "3430.4",
                            "RoomStatusDetails" => [],
                            "SupplementDetails" => [
                                "Supplement" => [
                                    "Id" => "403880",
                                    "FromDate" => "20191015",
                                    "ToDate" => "20191018",
                                    "Qty" => "1",
                                    "Rate" => "127",
                                    "CommissionSellCharges" => [],
                                    "TaxSellCharges" => [],
                                    "BuyRate" => [],
                                    "Name" => "CHILD SUPPLEMENT",
                                    "OptionalYN" => "N",
                                    "ValidOn" => "YYYYYYY",
                                    "Nights" => "4",
                                ]
                            ],
                            "DiscountDetails" => [
                                "Discount" => [
                                    "DiscountName" => "EARLY BIRD OFFER 2019-2020  20 % DISCOUNT",
                                    "DiscountType" => "Price Reduction Discount",
                                    "DiscountNotes" => "<html><body><p><strong>EARLY BIRD OFFER 2019 - 2020 | 20% DISCOUNT <br /><br />Terms and Conditions:</strong> <br />- Applicable for all booking received&nbsp;6 ",
                                    "DiscountTypeCode" => "0",
                                    "TotalDiscountRate" => "857.6",
                                    "CommissionSellCharges" => [],
                                    "TaxSellCharges" => [],
                                    "TotalDiscountBuyRate" => [],
                                ],
                            ],
                            "PromotionalContract" => "N",
                        ], 1 => [
                            "RoomNo" => "1",
                            "RoomType" => "DELUXE ROOM",
                            "RoomTypeCode" => "14264",
                            "RoomStatus" => "OK",
                            "BlackOut" => [],
                            "CurrCode" => "AED",
                            "ContractTokenId" => "191032",
                            "RoomConfigurationId" => "1",
                            "DynamicInventory" => "N",
                            "ContractLabel" => [],
                            "Refundable" => "Y",
                            "PackageYN" => "N",
                            "MealPlan" => "BED AND BREAKFAST",
                            "MealPlanCode" => "1376",
                            "RoomNumber" => "1",
                            "BuyRate" => [],
                            "CommissionSellCharges" => [],
                            "TaxSellCharges" => [],
                            "Rate" => "4019.2",
                            "RoomStatusDetails" => [],
                            "SupplementDetails" => [],
                            "DiscountDetails" => [],
                            "PromotionalContract" => "N",
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return data_get($data,'RoomTypeDetails.Rooms.Room.*.MealPlan');
```

This will give you:

```
[
"ROOM ONLY",
"BED AND BREAKFAST"
]
```

**Update:**

Just as @simonecosci mentioned to get individual value using "dot" notation you may use [array_get](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-get) so that you'll have:

```
array_get($data,'RoomTypeDetails.Rooms.Room.1.MealPlan')
```

The advantage of using this method apart from avoiding `foreach` is that it returns `null` when the property/index does not exist in the array.

Comment: Let me give a try. But as i have mention i can access all the elements of a single room EXCEPT the SupplementDetails and DiscountDetails Keys. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [array_get](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-get) should be afaik

Comment: good point @simonecosci . `data_get()` works like `Array::pluck()` or `Collection::pluck()`

Comment: Very helpful, this is working too mate! i can use this inside an foreach loop too right?

Comment: yes you can, but you shouldn't need to (depends on you though)

Comment: One prob, i cant echo the data, i can only print the data. When echoing It throws an "Array to string conversion", whats the quickest work around?

Comment: You shouldn't echo an array, you can use `print_r` btw, aren't you using Laravel if I may ask why you're using `echo` in your code?